# Curl in an infinite loop to POST to rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, devise

I am new to RoR apps.. and had implemented Devise as authentication.
Everything was going on fine.. until I discovered, that I was able to create users via curl command by POST method as below:

```
curl -d "user[username]=hacker&user[email]=hacker@test.com&user[password]=password&user[password_confirmation]=password&user[admin]=1" http://lvh.me:3000/users/
```

What if someone runs the curl command in an infinite loop..  is there a way to protect it ?

If I use attribute_accessible to not expose the fields, then I wont be able to create the users from the app itself..

I could not find anything in Google also.
Please help me understand if this is normal.?

UPDATE1:

Here is a sample app deployed to heroku http://intense-cliffs-5986.herokuapp.com/

Now Use the curl command

```
curl -d "user[name]=Somename&user[email]=Someone@test.com&user[password]=password&user[password_confirmation]=password" http://intense-cliffs-5986.herokuapp.com/users
```

On visiting the URL from browser you will see a new user created.

Is this normal... please help me understand.

UPDATE2:

Raised it to devise, lets see if they can answer. [Devise Issue 2613](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2613)

UPDATE3:

Devise team has answered at github. Seems Like its a desired feature. and they closed the issue.
I would have to find out another way now.

Comment: Do you have protect_from_forgery method call in your application controller? Look at this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html I think it will be helpful for you

Comment: Yes , I do have protect_from_forgery in my application controller.
Even then I was able to create a user with POST through curl.

Comment: @screenmutt, I have created a sample app and updated my question above.